# Identify this genre and performance: DJ with live instruments

Tags: electronic-music, jazz, identify-this-genre, dj

I am trying to identify the correct terminology for a particular performance type (or genre) that has a DJ + musician that makes the music live.

For example:

- [Darkside - Live on KEXP](https://youtu.be/Q__0zE0URbg?t=33s)
- [Gramatik - Live in Brussels](https://youtube.com/watch?v=irqC7oTlen4)

Notice that there is a **DJ** aspect to it (looping + mixing; the DJ is intricate to the production) and an **instrumental performance** (in this case a guitar and keyboard) +/- **singing**. And most importantly it's **recorded/performed live**.

I am in NYC and want to find music like this. It sounds like DeepHouse/Electronica/Jazz, but being created live. Although, 'Electronica' usually doesn't have a dance/hip-hop type beat to it, which is why I prefer the term 'House'. 'Live electronica' turns up Google results, but when I listen to songs from those performers, it lacks the heavy base line that the track I linked has. Another example with strong baselines: https://youtube.com/watch?v=vp3XlLx_oWo

There must be venues in NYC that have live productions of this genre on the regular. But to find them I need to know what this genre is called. **Can you accurately identify this genre so music and venues of this genre can be found?**

Comment: As your title stands now it's clickbait, and not descriptive of the content of your question. I'd suggest including the artists whose genre you are searching for.

Comment: Why is it "click-bait"? I don't want to tie myself to an artist for this. I've also included two additional links from another artist. I can easily include 10 more artists/songs, but I thought that would be overkill. It's not simply the "genre", but also the "performance type". Someone in the other post mentioned "experimental" as the performance type. Also, I'm confused why you'd choose to close this.

Comment: How is this off-topic?

Comment: The title is clickbait because it gives just enough info to make readers curious, but not enough to give readers any idea what the question is about. I didn't vote to close this question, but I can see how others would.

Comment: Vote to close because of the title? Or because asking about genre and performance-type are off-topic?

Comment: I assume it's because of the content of the question. I think it looks like genre identification questions will be off topic here: http://meta.musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/34/identify-this-song-genre-artist-on-topic

Comment: Since identify genre questions are no longer off-topic, I am voting to reopen.

Answer (score 4):

Darkside (Nicolas Jaar & Dave Harrington) is an [exceptionally talented and unique duo](http://www.nytimes.com/2013/10/13/magazine/nicolas-jaar-tests-the-limits-of-dance-music.html?_r=0). About a year ago I was lucky enough to see them at an intimate Brooklyn venue that no longer exists (RIP Glasslands).

You'll have trouble finding another band quite like them, though it's probably fair to say they exhibit traits of trip-hop, electronica, downtempo, and maybe deep house.

As for venues that might cater to this "genre", try: Le Poisson Rouge or NUBLU. Though you'll probably be better off identifying an act that interests you (try [Resident Advisor](http://www.residentadvisor.net/events.aspx)) and then following that act to whatever venue they're playing at.

Lucky for you, you live in NYC. You have many options.

Comment: They are certainly exceptionally talented. I know quite a few bands that do something similar (e.g., Gramatik), it's just that I can't seem to locate them consistently, partly because I can't accurately describe the genre or performance type. I want to call it "Live House Jazz", but that doesn't really find me relevant results. Live House ends up being just a DJ. Live jazz is just regular jazz. Not sure how to be more precise.

Comment: Also, Le Poisson Rouge is simply a live music venue. They have all sorts of stuff. I don't want to pay cover for that place day after day until I land at my intended genre on one set. Hence, how can I specifically identify this type of genre/performance?