# How is song qualified for being categorized as Sufi?

Tags: genre-characteristics

In Indian/Pakistani music, there is a genre called Sufi. What is it about Sufi music that defines it as such?

Comment: Clearly, the answer you received is an opinion and not concrete. Thereby, this question should be closed as it's akin to https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/70/what-is-the-correct-terminology-for-this-genre-and-type-of-performance. Which you should have no issue with, since you voted to close it

Comment: @Raj didn't we discussed it before and didn't we got disagree with each other? If still you think its urgent to discuss over it then better take it to meta then this random comments here and there.

Comment: I'm discussing the merits of this question as a comment to the question. That's a suitable place for discussion. Clearly, this answer has received only an opinion with a far from concrete answer for understanding the sufi terminology. How is that any different than trying to elucidate the terminology for a performance style @ https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/70/what-is-the-correct-terminology-for-this-genre-and-type-of-performance -- it's not a simple genre question. It's asking the performance style. Just like DJing, live looping, etc, aren't genres, they are performance styles.

Comment: @Raj Constructive discussion of a single question can be done in the comments, but comparisons of questions is a meta topic.

Comment: @ChrisSunami discussing the question required a comparison.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From [Wikipedia:](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sufi_music)

> Sufi music is the devotional music of the Sufis, inspired by the works
>   of Sufi poets, like Rumi, Hafiz, Bulleh Shah, Amir Khusrow and Khwaja
>   Ghulam Farid.

[What is Sufi Music:](http://devotionalmusic.weebly.com/sufi-music.html)

> Sufi music is not about entertainment; it is more about spirituality.
>   Its powerful lyrics talk about reaching the divine by spreading love
>   and harmony.

Sufi Music is:

- More about Spirituality.
- Inspired around poets works.
- Devotional Music.

I don't know if this helps.